# How to retrieve the second record in a group chronologically using Transact-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Given data like this:

```
SHQSCriteria            PropertyRef ReplacementYear
Energy Efficient            31          2014/15
Healthy, Safe & Secure      31          2012/13
Energy Efficient            462         2014/15
Healthy, Safe & Secure      462         2012/13
Free From Serious Disrepair 497         2012/13
Healthy, Safe & Secure      497         2012/13
Tolerable Standard          497         2012/13
Free From Serious Disrepair 498         2012/13
Healthy, Safe & Secure      498         2013/14
Tolerable Standard          498         2014/15
```

I want to pull out all the properties that fail more than one criterion, with the year that they fail the second criterion.

So, I want records that appear in the above list at least twice, but the replacement year is the second chronologically. Like this:

```
PropertyRef ReplacementYear
   31           2014/15
   462          2014/15
   497          2012/13
   498          2013/14
```

Please note that in this example properties 497 and 498 both fail three criteria. 497 fails all in the same year, so we should return that year. But 498 fails in 3 different years so we should return the second year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `CTE` and `row_number()` for Sql-Server 2008 and above;

```
;with cte as (
  select propertyRef, replacementYear,
         row_number() over (partition by propertyref order by replacementYear) rn
  from table
)
select * from cte
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a common table expression to order the years within each PropertyRef (and number them), then join that back to the data, specifying the second one for each PropertyRef:

```
WITH cte AS (
            SELECT  PropertyRef,
                    Years,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyref ORDER BY years) as RowNumber
            FROM    data
)
SELECT      d.PropertyRef,
            cte.Years
FROM        data d
INNER JOIN  cte
ON          cte.PropertyRef = d.PropertyRef
AND         cte.RowNumber = 2
GROUP BY    d.PropertyRef,
            cte.Years
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You don't really need the join and group by in the outer query. You can do the count inside the CTE as well (count(*) over (partition by propertyref, years) as cnt. That should be a bit faster than the self-join

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. Looking at Kaf's answer, you can use the same CTE and you don't even need the count - it's much simpler.